# Arduino IDE Flora - Greyed Out Ports

Tags: arduino, ide, usb, hardware, adafruit

I'm trying to learn how to use the Adafruit Flora, and I have followed the guides below:

https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-flora/windows-setup

https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-flora/blink-onboard-led

But, I'm struggling withe connecting to a port. It's greyed out in my IDE and I have tried a lot of things like, booting to BIOS and changing the settings to auto, to looking in for any hidden devices in the device manager window. I can't see a "Ports COM" section there and it's preventing me from uploading anything to the flora.

```
Arduino: 1.6.11 (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Flora"

Couldn't find a Board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct 
port selected.  If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button 
after initiating the upload.
```

Please help!

Comment: Is the usb cable working? Otherwise windows should be searching for drivers.

Comment: When I plug the flora in, it's pwr light is on and the d7 is blinking red.

Comment: USB Power cable can do this too except for establishing communication as data lines are not connected.

Comment: Funny enough, the cord I was using was supplied by Adafruit, but when I tried another power cord.. it worked.

Comment: Maybe faulty one. I'll make an answer from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check your usb cable. It might be faulty one or it could be charge only. If your board light/blink, it mean power lines are ok. But if there is no action from OS, there might be communication lines broken or missing.